# Editors that can enforce exact (not maximum) line length?

Tags: windows, editor

Does anyone know of an editor that has the ability to enforce exact line lengths (bonus if it allows association of maximum line lengths by file name/extension)?

What I mean by *exact line lengths* is that the editor will always save each line padded to a maximum line length (defined by the user).  For example, if a file should have a 120-character line length every line in the file will be 120-characters long, padded with blanks if needed, follow by the appropriate newline indicator.  When someone edits a line the editor will prevent them from typing if the line length hits the max length.

Platform is Win XP/Vista.

Comment: The short answer is: We are porting systems over to WIN32 from z/OS. One module handled the loading of data into memory from a custom file system. We have a great number of other modules dependant on the structure of that data being loaded. Due to the nature of data sets on the mainframe the records are padded to the LRECL attribute of the data set.  On the mainframe users were able to edit these data tables with ISPF Edit. We need to give the users a way to edit the data as they normally would, but without the fear tha a non-savvy user is going to screw up the data.

Comment: I was also looking for the path of least resistance solution.  Time is something that is not on our side at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Vim](http://www.vim.org/)

```
:syn match Error /^.{,119}$/
:syn match Error /.{121,}/
```

This will cause any lines of length != 120 to be highlighted with a solid red background (in the default color scheme).

If you write this (without the leading colons) into `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/foo.vim`, and place

```
:au BufRead,BufNewFile *.foo    set filetype=foo
:au Syntax foo  source $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/foo.vim
```

in `vimrc` or the usual `ftdetect` and `synload.vim` locations, then as long as syntax highlighting is enabled, these rules will will automatically apply to any `*.foo` file you open in Vim.

(See [`:h mysyntaxfile-add`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#mysyntaxfile-add) if you want to add to an existing syntax file, and see [`:h rtp`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#vimfiles) for the default `$VIMRUNTIME` path on your platform.)

Comment: While not exactly enforcing, at least this provides a visual cue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of an editor that handles this type of input, however, I can say that overall it wouldn't be that hard to actually create a system that works in this manner.

Comment: I agree we could create something and I'd also like to think that "overall it wouldn't be that hard," but when I do my coder-sense tingles warning me that writing a robust editor of any kind is always == !!hard.

Answer (score 0):

The [Zeus editor](http://www.zeusedit.com/) can't enforce this rule, but by using a *two stage search and replace* it would be possible to convert a file into this format in a *semi-automatic* fashion.

**Step One:** Make saure all lines are longer than 120 characters by running the following regexp search and replace to pad the strings.

```
 Search: (.*)\n
Replace: \1                              \n
```

**NOTE:** The replace string shown above should have *120 white space characters* and not just the 30 shown.

**Step Two:** Trim the lines at the 120 character mark using this regexp search and replace.

```
 Search: ^(.{120,120})(.*)\n
Replace: /1\n
```

At this point all the lines in the file will be exactly 120 characters in length.

But to make sure these lengths stick, make sure the Zeus option to *trim lines of white on save* is disabled ;)

Also since Zeus is scriptable, it would be possible to semi-automate this process by writing a simple macro script to run these two operations.

Finally Zeus has an option to run a macro script on a trigger so the macro could be added to the [save trigger](http://www.zeusedit.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1770) to make it semi-automatic.

I am sure it would be possible to configure any scriptable editor to do something similar.